# How to get all text from divs that have class="title" in android by JSOUP?

Tags: android, html, jsoup, gettext

I use this code but not true !!! why...?

```
String url = "http://example.com";
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Using Elements to get the Meta data
            Elements description = document
                    .select("div[class=title]");
            // Locate the content attribute
            desc = description.attr("content");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

if my html code is

```
<div class="text-co">
<div class="title"><a href="">00</a>
                   <a href="">11</a>
                   <a href="">22</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="text-co">
<div class="title"><a href="">33</a>
                   <a href="">44</a>
                   <a href="">55</a>
</div>
</div>
```

and I want to show
00
11
22
33
44
55
in my android app by **jsoup**,What should I do

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Try `desc = description.text();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Elements anchors = document.select("div.title > a");
for(Element anchor : anchors) {
   Strig description = anchor.text();
   // ...
}
```